# make the form and button on the same line

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I would like the make the text field on the same line of the button, but not successful.

Need some helps.

HTML

```
<form id="newsletter_form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter you mail here ..." /><input type="image" src="images/go_button.jpg" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
#newsletter_form
{
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
}
#newsletter_form input[type="text"]
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/yokosatan/GbtZy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your `input[type="text"]` `vertical-align:top`

**as like this**

```
#newsletter_form input[type="text"] {
vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/GbtZy/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just float the first input to the left:

**Markup**

```
<form id="newsletter_form">
     <input type="text" class="lefty" placeholder="Enter you mail here ..." />
     <input type="image" class="clear" src="http://s21.postimg.org/n786rdtfn/go_button.jpg" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.lefty {
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GbtZy/3/

Its worth reading up on floats and how to understand them. Its important to clear after using them, otherwise other things will get a little confusing.

[Floats CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should select your input element and give `vertical-align: middle;` to be displayed properly.

```
#newsletter_form input
{
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GbtZy/7/)

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
<form id="newsletter_form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter you mail here ..." />
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="image" src="images/go_button.jpg" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

or Edit your css like this

```
 #newsletter_form input[type="text"]
        {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
```

you need to define input type for vertical-align work